# Git Authentication Failed, remote: invalid username or password

Tags: github, passwords

I am trying to push some edits from my local repo to my GitHub but I get this error:

```
(base) herasyed@MacBook-Air-3 MechaCar_Statistical_Analysis % git add .       
(base) herasyed@MacBook-Air-3 MechaCar_Statistical_Analysis % git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .DS_Store
    renamed:    MechaCarChallenge.R -> R Code/MechaCarChallenge.R

(base) herasyed@MacBook-Air-3 MechaCar_Statistical_Analysis % git push
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/herasyed/MechaCar_Statistical_Analysis.git/'
```

I can pull from my Git fine and my SSH key seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

> my SSH key seems to be working.

Your SSH key is not used at all, considering the remote URL used is an HTTPS one.

If you want to use SSH:

```bash
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:herasyed/MechaCar_Statistical_Analysis.git
git push
```

See if the push succeeds then.